# CreateRemoteThread, error 5

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, code-injection

I am trying to inject a stub into a 64 bit Windows process from my 32 bit process, and then remotely start a thread in the x64 process. This is causing some problems because winapi's [CreateRemoteThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx) is throwing error-code 5 which translates to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, no matter which flags I use when calling [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx). I read that this was because Windows won't allow injection "cross-platform", but I don't think this is the problem since the code injects fine.

I am using `GetLastError()` right after the call to `CreateRemoteThread()` and it shows error-code 5.

I am using this set of flags for `OpenProcess`, with no success:

```
PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE
```

as well as just `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`.

Anyone have an idea what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calls to `CreateRemoteThread` made from a 32 bit process, where the target process is 64 bit are not supported. You'll need to call `CreateRemoteThread` from a 64 bit process.

Comment: Just to be sure; there is no way around this?

Comment: The way round is to use a 64 bit process!

Comment: Well, thanks, though it's not an option as I'd have to rewrite the whole application

Comment: @PeterJensen: You don't have to rewrite your application. Have your application launch a 64-bit surrogate process, that creates the remote thread and work it from there.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the comment. That sounds like a great solution! I've looked into it, and it doesn't seem like there is too much info - Do you know where I can find some examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Examples? Call CreateProcess to create a new process.

Comment: False. How would you ever spawn a 64-bit process of an .exe compiled for x86, using CreateProcess? That is certainly not possible.
@IInspectable More info would be nice :-)

Comment: Nobody said that you could make a 32 bit executable run as a 64 bit process. I think you have not understood what @IInspectable and I are saying.

Comment: That is why I am asking what is meant by "surrogate process". I would really appreciate if you could elaborate.
Do you mean that I could write a small 64-bit application specifically for injecting the stub, and pack this binary as a resource and have it started if it's running on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Something like that. I don't think I'd pack it as a resource. I'd just deploy it alongside your main app. But that's your choice

Comment: Ah, okay. Just wanted it to function as simple and seamlessly as possible, and it would be cool if it was shipped as just a single file, but doesn't matter too much how I'm going to do it.
I'm now marking this as the answer, and this question can be considered closed. Again, thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. You can not run 32-bit code in a 64-bit process, and you can't run 64-bit code in a 32-bit process.

Solution is to rebuild your injection code as 64-bit.

This is by design. The processor simply doesn't work exactly the same in 32- and 64-bit mode, and you can't trivially switch from one mode to the other and back again. Several things are dramatically different:

- Push and Pop instructions are always 64-bit in 64-bit mode. So 32-bit code would push 64 bit values, and thus `void foo(int x, int y)` would get a 64-bit `x` covering both `x` and `y`. This affects offsets for variables on the stack and everything else inside the functions.
- Actual calling convention is different - 32-bit mode uses different and fewer registers to pass arguments to functions (if any arguments are passed by register - it's optional), where 64-bit mode always uses registers and more registers. So calls from 32-bit mode would have the data in the wrong place for 64-bit mode, etc.
- Instruction encoding for some common instructions is different - primarily that 0x40-0x4f are single byte instructions to PUSH/POP all registers, where this range is the REX (Register Extension) prefix in 64-bit mode. 64-bit mode uses a two-byte encoding [which was introduced to allow a more flexible set of PUSH/POP instructions, with multiple addressing modes described within the second byte]

There are dozens of other things that are different too, but these should be enough to show that "it doesn't work like that".

Comment: Dynamic Processor Mode Switching http://rce.co/knockin-on-heavens-gate-dynamic-processor-mode-switching/

Comment: @Balu Have you tried that solution? I see that it involves ASM. I am wondering if this is a solid way around the problem?

Comment: @PeterJensen yes it involves some assembly coding to change the code segment register . It will work, I used it to inject the 64 bit dll in a 32 bit wow64 process.

Comment: But you have to then convince the REMOTE process to do these things. I would say my answer stands: you can't do this. Is it possible to make the processor run 32-bit code in a 64-bit process, yes. But it's non-trivial and not the right solution to this problem. Just build the injector as 64-bit.

Comment: Asker isn't trying to execute 32 bit code in a 64 bit process. Asker is trying to start a new thread in a 64 bit process, but call `CreateRemoteThread` from a 32 bit process. This answer is accurate, but an answer to a different question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Exactly! It is CreateRemoteThread throwing the error. Maybe I wasn't clear enough when writing the question. But well, that sucks. Anyway, thanks for the answer - Now I can move on with the project.